# Stylistic Advice regarding the two types of possessives before a gerund

Tags: possessives, gerunds

I know that, in terms of formal grammar, either a possessive pronoun or genitive form should precede a gerund. So, for example, 'his being', etc.

I am, however, far more comfortable with the former than the latter: I have read it more. Moreover, some writers - thinking mostly of academics, who are likely to know (and apply) the possessive/gerund rule - will apply the former rule while neglecting the latter rule. Why is this?

To take the example with which I am struggling:

Despite Smith borrowing from Brown, he innovated in his political thought where necessary.

Now, according to the rule, this phrase should be rewritten as: 'Despite Smith's borrowing from Brown, he innovated in his political thought where necessary.'

This is for a final-year dissertation at university, so it is obviously for a formal piece of work. Is is ttherefore advisable that I use the possessive/gerund rule? And, related to that, why does the possessive pronoun (his borrowing) sound correct (if a little stilted), but the genitive (Smith's borrowing) sounds as if the writer or speaker is not a native speaker and has an incomplete grasp of the language.

Comment: It will depend on the prejudices of those who will read your dissertation, so ask them. All we can tell you is that **either** the possessive (aka genitive) form (_my, his, Bill's_) **or** the basic (aka objective) form (_me, him, Bill_) can mark the subject of a gerund clause. The only kind of NP that **can't** mark gerund subjects is a nominative (_I, he_), which is limited to pronouns anyway.

Comment: There's no "rule". If we rewrite it as a choice between "Despite him borrowing from Brown, Smith..." and "Despite his borrowing from Brown, Smith..." it's easier to see that both are in common usage, and the decision remains a matter of *style* (consult your university's style manual), and whether you want to use a more formal *register* (i.e. his/Smith's). The choice is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

In formal, traditional grammar, you would indeed want to use the possessive before a gerund:

> *Despite Smith's borrowing from Brown, he innovated in his political thought where necessary.*

But now you have another problem (at least according to some grammarians): the possessive as antecedent. In the above sentence, *Smith's* is an adjective modifying the gerund *borrowing*, yet *he* refers to *Smith*, who's nowhere to be found here.

One might think that *he* = *Smith* is obvious. In fact many other grammarians find the structure acceptable.

Since you never know which grammarian your paper will come up against, let's write your worries away:

> *Despite borrowing from Brown, Smith innovated in his political thought where necessary.*

What I think you might actually be trying to say is:

> *Although Smith borrowed from Brown, he innovated in his political thought where necessary.*

And since *innovated in* a bit dodgy in form, perhaps:

> *Although Smith borrowed from Brown, he was innovative in his political thought when necessary.*

For more discussion of possessive antecedents, see [Possessive antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_antecedent) and [The Nation: Parts of Speech; The Bloody Crossroads of Grammar and Politics](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/06/01/weekinreview/the-nation-parts-of-speech-the-bloody-crossroads-of-grammar-and-politics.html).